# How to apply Custom language on Digits iOS SDK view

Tags: ios, mobile, twitter-fabric

Want to change text of view on Digits iOS SDK, does any one know how we can change the text with custom language from code.

https://fabric.io/kits/android/digits/features[image: d]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digits PM here. Currently it's not possible to override the Digits SDK views with your own language. May I ask which language you would like to support?

We support 32+ languages in our SDK authentication views, SMS messages and voice verification calls. A full list of supported languages is [here](https://get.digits.com/international-growth).

The language of the interface(s) is automatically chosen based on the local of the end user's device.

Comment: The SDK has a bug, as the very first time we will sometimes receive English SMS rather than Chinese one. Second and following message are  sent in Chinese, but most user won't repeat this process. Also I live in Taiwan, using traditional Chinese, but only simplified Chinese is available.